# Give positive integers $m$, $n$ and example of $m \times n$ matrix $A$ with the following property:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

$Ax=b$ has no solutions for some $b \in \Bbb R^n$, and one solution for every other $b \in \Bbb R^n$.

Can you please explain the reasoning behind your answer?

Comment: Can you at least provide your own examples? Think small, $1\times 2$ or $2 \times 1$ matrices.

Comment: it's suppose to be a general question for any $m$ and $n$

Comment: @RaghavKedia What Evan is asking is whether you can find such a matrix for specific $m$ and $n$, since it will guide you in finding the general solution.

Comment: It is a bit confusing to use $b$ as name for any vector other than $b$.

Comment: Also your question seems very unclear. Only one $m \times n$ example? Do you want conditions for which these properties are satisfied?

Comment: The title isn't supposed to be the first line of your question.

Comment: If for some $b\in\Bbb R^n$ the equation $Ax=b$ has no solutions, then $b$ is certainly _not the only_ vector for which this failure happens. There will be vectors that do give solutions (for instance $\vec0$ always does), but they will be a minority.

Comment: Do you possibly mean to say there _are_ some $b$'s without solutions, while there are also other $b$'s with a solution?

Comment: ^yea that is what i mean

Comment: @Raghav Kedia:  well, if that's what you mean, then it might help if you edited/re-wrote the question to define the set of $b$s without solution.  I think knowing which $b$s have no solution will help define the set of those which do!  ;)  Anyway, I answered the original question!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you’ve stated the problem correctly? There is no such example.

If $Ax=b$ has no solutions, and $\alpha\ne 0$, then $Ax=\alpha b$ has no solutions: if $Ax=\alpha b$, then $A\left(\alpha^{-1}x\right)=b$. Thus, if $b$ is the **only** vector in $\Bbb R^n$ for which the equation has no solutions, then $b=0$, so that $\alpha b=b$ for all $\alpha\in\Bbb R$. In other words, you’re looking for $m,n$, and an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $Ax=0$ has no solution, but $Ax=b$ has one solution for each non-zero $b\in\Bbb R^n$. This, however, is impossible, since the homogeneous equation $Ax=0$ **always** has the solution $x=0$.

**Added:** If you want an example in which $Ax=b$ has solutions for some choices of $b$ but has no solution for other choices of $b$, start with a really simple example with no solutions, like

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\;;\tag{1}$$

can you see why $(1)$ has no solution? And can you see a way to change the righthand side to get a matrix equation with the same coefficient matrix that **does** have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very similar in spirit to Brian's:  If $Ax = b$ has no solution, but $Ax = c$ has a solution for every $c \ne b$, then pick $c_1 \in R^n$, $c_1 \ne b$, $c_1 \ne 0$, and find $x_1$ such that $Ax_1 = c_1$.  Now, we can assume $b \ne 0$ since $A0 = 0$; taking $b = 0$ always admits zero as a solution.  So set $c_2 = c_1 + b$.  Then since
$b \ne 0$, $c_2 \ne c_1$, and since $c_1 \ne 0$, $c_2 \ne b$.  So there is an $x_2$ with $Ax_2 = c_2$.  But then $A(x_2 - x_1) = Ax_2 - Ax_1 = c_2 - c_1 = b$, a contradiction.

So I can't give an example of such an $A$ as the OP requests, for there is none to be had.  At least knowing this will save some time in the search for such $A$!

Well, I *hope* this helps! Cheers!